# jQuery hide / show content based on common parent

Tags: jquery, html, parent

I've this repeated HTML code.

```
<div id="id1" class="questio">   
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Content</div>   
</div>

<div id="id2" class="questio">    
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>
</div>

<div id="id3" class="questio">   
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>    
</div>
```

The wanted behaviour is to hide / show div c2 Content for each section **independently** based on input.c1 checked or not:

```
if ($(".c1").is(":checked")) {     
  $('.c2').show(); 
}
```

I tried somethig like this but I can't go on :

```
$("input.c1").each(function() {
  var parent1 = $(this).closest('questio');     
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        /// ??
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close.

```
//you can find the c1's that are checked
$(".c1:checked").each(function() {
    //you can then find their parent questio (with the '.' for the selector)
    //then find the related c2 and show it.
    $(this).closest('.questio').find('.c2').show();
});
```

Though given your markup you could do this entirely with css.

```css
.questio .c1:not(:checked) + .c2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="questio">
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Content</div>
</div>

<div id="id2" class="questio">
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>
</div>

<div id="id3" class="questio">
  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exaclty what I was looking for! Using the common parent to isoIate the function behaviour! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being clicked on, otherwise you're targeting too many elements you don't need.

```js
$('input.c1').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div.c2').toggle($(this).is(":checked"))
})
```

```css
.c2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Content</div>

</div>

<div id="id2" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>

</div>

<div id="id3" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var div1 = $("id1");
var c2OfDiv1 = div1.find(".c2");
c2OfDiv1.hide(); //or c2OfDiv1.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent(), like this short-hand:

```js
$(".c1").on('change', function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent().find('.c2');
  parent[$(this).is(":checked") ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

```css
.c2 {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Content</div>

</div>

<div id="id2" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>

</div>

<div id="id3" class="questio">

  <input type="checkbox" class="c1">
  <div class="c2">Another Content</div>

</div>
```